# What is minimum content size of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c

I'm attaching my location details and 3 images (about 3mb each) to the mail and when i click on send button i see a pop-up asking me "This message is 2.0 MB. You can reduce message size by scaling images to one of the sizes below." And it ask me for "small", "medium" and "actual" size.

I want to know the required minimum mail attachment size. Or whether i can avoid this pop-up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you min the maximum?

Comment: There is no such minimum file size available, its just a recommendation of file size, some times you don't want to send actual file rather your goal can be achieved with medium size file. You can choose any option according to your need. For maximum file size is dependent on your mail client. Choose best suited attachment compression. You can't avoid that popup.